# Ideal Firearms for time travel or low tech universe exploration

Tags: weapons, medieval, history, firearms

I am a world-hopping warlock who regularly goes on adventures in various worlds with differing levels of technological knowledge. Being a crafty warlock, I have a number of tricks, weapons, and gadgets up my sleeves, and I'd like to add firearms to my repertoire.

I'm currently planning an extended campaign in Acardia, a continent with a technological and political structure comparable to what you folks refer to as early medieval Europe. My early scouting missions haven't discovered any gunpowder based weapons, although I can't confirm that no such thing exists there.

Once the campaign starts in earnest, It won't be feasible to return to a more advanced world for supplies. In addition, I'll be traveling a great deal, so I don't want to cart heavy machinery around with me. I'd like to utilize firearms as a form of self defense during this campaign.

Here's the thing, though- I don't want to be that idiot who thinks they can conquer an entire continent with a single machine gun. If I'm going to use firearms in this campaign, I need to take into account the manufacture of ammunition, repair of the weapons, etcetera.

So... what's the most advanced sort of gun I can take with me and be able to utilize for the entire campaign, which could last for years? It's acceptable if the guns themselves can't be manufactured using the tools available, so long as they can be maintained using Acardian tech. I will, however, need to manufacture ammunition. I would also prefer to be able to fire more than once before reloading, and use bullets that include powder inside of them rather than being loose metal balls (if possible). (If I'm correct, guns that use such bullets tend to be easier to clean.)

I'll be campaigning with a small team, no more than 20 to 30 people. I don't currently have a motor vehicle that would be practical to fuel and maintain during the campaign, so I'll probably be using horse-drawn wagons to carry anything I need to take with me.

If the tools required to make ammunition or a part can themselves be easily made with Acardian tech, that is also acceptable, but keep in mind I won't have the resources to start an industrial revolution. If the equipment in question is too heavy to cart around, and I can't make new ones when I enter a new city, that will put a damper on it, but it won't necessarily completely invalidate the technique in question.

I'd also like to note that, given the choice between power and accuracy, I'd probably go for accuracy, although it would certainly be nice if the gun had the power to punch through steel plate.

Comment: Self-defence against what - human bandits, lions, polar bears, elephants, royal families that do not wish to step down in your favour?  How often are you expecting to need to "defend yourself" that it is not easier to just take a reliable modern firearm, some standard spare parts (eg firing pin) and a couple of hundred rounds each?  Is it important to conceal your firearms from the local populace?

Comment: YOu'll be burned as a witch, tho.

Comment: You should take care. Acardia is regarded as a heartless civilization.

Comment: What do you mean by punching through a steel plate? Most modern handheld firearms are not suited for that.

Comment: How advanced is your technology? Is something like a 1000 GW laser ray hand-implanted device powered by a tiny fusion generator which also provides a 360° shielding available?

Comment: Self defence against all of the above, I suppose. We'll see. (us warlocks have a bad habit of getting involved with politics, which occasionally results in... shall we say, "brutal warfare"? (Don't worry, we're not ALWAYS the bad guys.)) As for the steel plate, I mean steel plate armor. (the kind you see in picture books.) I currently have access to a technological level more or less the same as yours.

Comment: @Globin347 "Steel plate armor" still means everything from Roman Lorica Segmentata of 2000 years ago up to 20th century lobster armor (at a stretch you could even include the steel plates of modern ballistic armor).

Comment: How many shots do you expect to fire?  It's hard to imagine you firing more than a couple hundred rounds in "self defense".  If you're attacked by 201 medieval highwaymen, chances are one of them's going to get you just by dumb luck.  So it's probably simpler to just buy a case of a thousand rounds for whatever rifle, rather than try to manufacture new ammo on the scene.

Comment: @workerjoe Not only that...I don't see why he couldn't take two guns. A second one for which ammo can be produced in-situ.

Comment: @Globin347 When you say "self-defense" are you talking about daily self-defense while going about a regular day? Or self-defense in times of war?

Comment: Ok, I see I still have unanswered questions. I guess I should expect to pierce late medieval or rennaissance armor at best, and while I don't expect to get into a firefight every day, I might get into such a fight a few times a week during longer missions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Solar Charging Electro-magnetic Flechette gun**

How advanced is the most advanced world you've encountered?

A Coil-gun is perhaps the most reliable weapon imaginable.
It fires reliably underwater, in space, in mud..
The entire weapon can be sealed in plastic and it has virtually no moving parts whatsoever.
It cannot jam, it doesn't misfire and requires almost no cleaning or maintenance.

The ammunition ideally would be iron-cored tungsten needles, but in a pinch, an iron nail will do just fine.
The flechette gun will put an iron nail through a two inch thick wooden beam at 100 paces, so armour-piercing capability is not a problem.
Ammunition can be manufactured by any blacksmith able to [Draw metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawing_(manufacturing))

The only technological hurdle is the power required to fire it.
Fortunately, the internal super-conducting capacitors have more than enough Oomph to get the job done.

In the field, such a weapon mounts a small solar cell in the casing that trickle-feeds the capacitors. It's not the most efficient way to charge it, (preferably you'd plug it into a base-station for charging) but it's more than sufficient if you have time on your hands.

Good news for you is that travelling between towns by horse and cart will take days, so you have plenty of time to keep your weapon charged!

Comment: Delicate electronics being bashed about while traveling through rugged adventures for years, and you expect that it will never need any maintenance or repair? That alone is heroic levels of super-advanced technology beyond the ken of man.

Comment: So...you travel between towns for days, and then you get a single shot. Better not miss.

Comment: Keep the electronics solid-state, no sub-components, it's all manufactured as a single brick of doped silicon. That's about as robust as it gets when it comes to electronics. We can do it with modern technology, but economies of scale mean working with sub-components is usually more efficient.

Comment: The super-conductive capacitors would have plenty of power for multiple shots, the entire point of them is rapid-discharge and much much higher capacity than a battery. You just keep them trickle-charging all the time and you'll probably be fine for multiple shots when you need them. Just be economical with how often you need to use the weapon! Don't pick fights unnecessarily.

Comment: Of course, for field-expedient charging, bring along a super-conductive cable. insert one end into your camp-fire and plug the other end into the gun. The resultant thermo-couple effects will rapidly charge your weapon with significantly more efficiency than the solar trickle-charger.

Comment: I mean, if we're going for future-tech, why not go all-in and install a small nuclear battery? Sure, it might be slightly carcinogenic, but, if lightweight shielding materials haven't been invented, you're still a a warlock. Curing cancer shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi I disagree, I have a laptop that I've been using for around eight years now (and not just on my desk) and I've never had to preform any physical repairs on it (and it has far more moving parts than a coilgun needs to have, which is zero). If we had the super-capacitors today that this coilgun needs, it could be engineered so that it could go decades without anything more than superficial maintenance.

Comment: @Dragongeek I'm guessing it never had to cope with being dumped in the river when your canoe overturned. There is a difference between sitting in climate controlled rooms vs the bump and tumble of traveling over broken ground through life in undeveloped territory for years. Moving parts are not the only thing that experience degradation - capacitors and resistors do corrode over time like everything else, but I suppose if you are handwaving super-capacitors you can handwave immortal components that never experience chemistry regardless of conditions. I certainly wouldn't bet my life on it.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi Designing electronics that work for years under tough conditions isn't anything new. For example, satellites launched 1970's which still work today despite extreme conditions (high g's, extreme temperatures/radiation). Electrical failures to to defective packaging are common (corrosives getting in), however, this is frequently solved by simply potting the whole assembly in something like polyurethane. Avoiding components that are failure prone (like electrolytic capacitors or mechanical relays) and following good engineering guidelines (like redundant systems) isn't impossible

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning, for the sake of other answers.. The first firearms initially fired wrought-iron flechettes in leather sabots, but they took enough work to manufacture that militaries switched to lead balls, which were less accurate, but far easier to mass-produce.

Comment: As an alternative to relying on solar power, why not have a kinetic charger like a pump or crank. Even a shake-weight-y type charger, while ridiculous to use, would probably be more reliable than solar. It would also be fairly simple to maintain and repair as one of the few sets of moving parts. At the most basic, it's simply a sci-fi'ed up dynamo charger. You would really only need to worry about power storage for a single shot or a single burst of shots.

Comment: More mechanical parts (and points of failure), plus the effort required to generate that kind of charge in the capacitors would be exorbitant. Better to use a super-conductive cable as a thermocouple and charge your weapon off the campfire.

Answer (score 24):

Best solution is to skip the gunpowder - too difficult to manufacture while traveling or carry vast quantities, and a bit of a pain to deal with anyway. Of course if you are relying upon the giant cloud of smoke to obscure you and the target and loud bang to scare the primitives off, then go with black powder, but honestly I would rather shoot them than mostly hope they scare easily.

I suggest an air rifle. For reference, the [Girandoni air rifle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girandoni_air_rifle) taken on expedition by Lewis and Clark certainly survived long arduous journeys through the wilderness. At one point the main spring broke and they modified a metal file to fit in its place. That kind basic design for field maintenance is vitally important when you don't have access to the same kind of workshops which produced it. A few modifications to the design (for example being able to braze a seam more effectively than they could at the time would make for a much more robust air canister than they had, and some rubber gaskets instead of leather though leather is very easy to acquire if replacement gaskets are needed) and this would be thoroughly reliable.

Of course there are any number of designs which could be used, but I like pointing out that repeating rifles capable of firing 20 shots in about a minute were fielded in 1780, and more specialized single-shot hunting weapons had been available for at least a century prior. Unfortunately they were a little delicate for poorly-trained masses of peasants to survive long use in the field (which was the style of warfare at the time) as well as mass-production manufacturing not quite being up to the level needed for sufficient reliability and interchangeable parts, but for small numbers (craft quality rather than mass-produced by poorly-skilled apprentices trying to churn them out by the hundreds) this would be the way to go.

A small metal shop (even some bronze working in antiquity would suffice) for major repairs, some leather for worn out gaskets, and some lead for ammunition (easily melted down and poured into molds at your everyday cooking fire while camping), and this would serve quite well. Downside is that the accompanying belt-pouch sized air pump took about 1500 strokes to recharge a 30 shot air canister - the wagon-mounted version was far better but not something an individual could walk around with.

If you were willing to go a little higher tech, you could make a more effective air rifle with better pumps for building pressure and a lighter more robust design, but the downside is relying upon modern alloys and delicate metalwork for replacement parts. Something which only needs knowledge to produce with low-tech manufacturing seems like a better path for reliability on campaign.

Comment: out of curiosity how robust would the belt pouch air pump be? Could that be a critical fault if that failed?

Comment: @BKlassen air pumps aren't that complex (though without good resources the repair might be clunky). The problems with pneumatic weapons were keeping the cost down for mass-production, which led to standard army issue being less than ideal quality, so I don't know that the Austrian army's experience really translates to a higher-quality version. I don't recall hearing of any of Lewis and Clark's issues with pumping the canisters (doesn't mean they didn't have any), but they spent over 2 years in the wilderness giving demonstrations to every tribe they met (gave potential attackers pause).

Comment: Some types of modern air rifles can shoot a pellet all the way through a  2x4. Technically, you don't even need an air compressor to recharge the tanks, a decent quality bike pump and a bit of patience would suffice.

Comment: @Jonathan As is mentioned in the answer, the Girandoni air rifle had a hand pump small enough to fit in a belt pouch, which soldiers were expected to carry along with all the rest of their kit. It could shoot all 24 rounds in their magazine through solid 1 inch thick planks at distances of at least 125 yards (obviously losing strength with each shot, but the canisters were expected to maintain lethal effectiveness for 30+ shots at 100 yards). If only the Austrian army in 1780 could have taught soldiers not to treat the equipment like junk, maybe it would have changed the face of warfare.

Comment: I was going to make this same suggestion.  Ammunition can be lead balls, easily produced from lead scraps over a campfire.  Materials other than lead can be used, though anything harder could produce significant wear on the barrel.  Casting lead "minni balls" are also possible though perhaps more time consuming, with the benefit of greater range and accuracy.  Suitable projectiles could likely be purchased or built by a suitable artisan or craftsman on a commission.  Their true purpose need not be revealed as they could easily be explained as game pieces, fishing weights, or other commodity.

Comment: Oh, I may have to explain what a minni ball is for people that are not familiar with muzzle loaded firearms and air rifles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini%C3%A9_ball  Modern air rifles commonly use a derivative on this idea.  There may be a desire to have both a smooth and rifled barrel available.  A rifled barrel is more accurate but limits ammunition options.  A smooth bore means having the option to load more than one projectile safely, making the rifle a shotgun.  Also possible is less than lethal projectiles, like a pepper ball, or a signal flare.  Use your imagination.

Answer (score 19):

I'd recommend the [Colt Pocket Percussion Revolver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colt_Pocket_Percussion_Revolvers), possibly supplemented with a good muzzleloader (they've got easy-to-maintain modern ones now) for ranged shots.

Sorry, I'm sticking you with ball and powder. Modern ammunition is pretty great, and not hard to make with modern techniques - but that's the thing. It's best with modern techniques to get the rifling and curvature right. I don't know what kind of tech level you'll be at, so I'm picking something which can be manufactured effectively at the lowest level.

Black powder isn't hard to make, all it takes is the correct natural resources. Look up a recipe online, I try to stay off as many government lists as I can. Ammunition is the real trick here - making a perfect sphere. And there's a very easy way to do that using gravity. Use a sixty foot tall building, strain lead through a copper mesh, and then drop 60ft into cold water. It's called a shot tower, and it produces very accurate lead balls for ammunition. Not as good as a modern round, but on the flip side, it won't have the defects something made with 10th century technology will have. Carry a few Colts for short range, a modern muzzleloader for long range, and take good care of them. Should work pretty well.

Edit: Percussion caps - these weren't made until the 1800s, but technically the chemistry is possible earlier. The hard part is the mercury fulminate, which can be made by combining mercury (pretty accessible), ethanol (widely accessible), and nitric acid (dangerous, but accessible even as early as the 900s) in a specific way. Nitric acid can be made from scratch, if you know what you're doing, but I'm *definitely* not including a recipe for that, as it's also a precursor to TNT.

Comment: You won't get put on a list for making black powder, the manufacture of ammunition is a widely accepted and cost-saving practice for gun lovers.

Comment: The problem with a revolver is the manufacture of the percussion caps. Even if you can manage to produce black powder with sufficient and reliable quality (not as easy as you may expect even if the theory is simple) for use in a pistol, you will rapidly run out of percussion caps which you cannot make without relatively advanced facilities (early 19th century). The shot tower is unnecessary - it makes mass-production easier, but for individual purposes a simple mold (tiny bit of cleanup to knock off the residual bits) is more practical on a personal scale (and completely portable).

Comment: @DisplayName Entirely depends on the country you are in.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that early firearms were used to fire wrought-iron flechettes sometimes, the musket-ball became popular because it was easy to manufacture in bulk, not because it was better. Flechettes were more accurate and better at piercing armour, but took more work and precision to make. They have the perk of working with any smoothbore muzzle-loaded weapon though. So vary your ammunition depending on your situation!

Answer (score 10):

All you really need is heat and knowledge. Copper and tin were very common metals in the world you describe, so the brass to manufacture ammunition is no problem.  Gunpowder existed - but only in China - so the early Europeans just hadn’t found it yet. It was there. He needs to be really good at making very precise recipes from natural ingredients. We are talking about a warlock, aren't we?

Getting gunpowder is easy:

- Your warlock needs to have access to tobacco, sunflower, common borage, or celandine sap which contains the saltpeter. He can also find it in limestone caves.
- He needs to get some charcoal. Just burn some wood.
- He needs to locate a geothermal area - hot springs or a volcano and try to get some sulfur.

When he plays around with these three ingredients he will have gunpowder.

He needs to make cartridge shells, not the ball musket. The important advantage of the cartridge over ball shot is keeping powder dry. All your weapons can become useless quickly in a slight drizzle, and you’ll be reloading under an umbrella. But, making cartridges is time consuming so I hope some of his magic can do automatic work for him! If he has access to electricity (or magical power) he can bring a modern ammunition stamp press, which can be mostly aluminum. Otherwise, he can make one when he gets there. It looks like this:
[image: Ammunition Stamp]

Many people make their own bullets today. Just be sure he can get the basic materials and he is good at making them pure. He can make bullets in any caliber. You don’t need special armor piercing bullets, the armor of that period will be worthless against him.

Pick any high powered rifle or guns you like for the trip, he can make ammunition, and he can maintain it with local mineral oils.

I want to add that you can improve your gunpowder with nitroglycerine, which can be made from the same ingredients. Take sulfuric acid and the salt Peter in a pan to make nitric acid. Use the nitric acid, sulfuric acid, and baking soda (mined from a mineral called trona, or made with CO2, ammonia, and table salt). This can give your ammo a little more range.

Your warlock needs to be really good at quality control or the bullets will be very unreliable. You don’t want duds! Make him a perfectionist!

Comment: Making cases, gunpowder, and bullets may be simple, but what about the fulminated mercury in the primer?  I believe that's more challenging, both in getting the recipe right and in not blowing yourself up while you do it.

Comment: Making black powder is relatively easy, but is it any good for a cartridge? ISTR that smokeless powder predated cartridges, and that's a bit more involved to manufacture.

Comment: Now would he really be a crafty warlock with a number of tricks, weapons, and gadgets up his sleeves if such a thing got in his way? In my mind, difficult and precise processes literally define sorcery.

Comment: Cooking nitroglycerin sounds like self-endangerment, not preparation for self-defense.

Comment: I’m writing everything with the mindset that this is a warlock. Everything he cooks up is very likely self-endangerment when done wrong. They earn their reputation through using patience, care, and discipline with hard to-master processes. If his weapons could be done by an everyday Joe using grocery store items, well, his advantage fades quickly.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Black powder works fine in cartridges.  It was used in the Martini-Henry rifle used by the British against the Zulu, for example.  But you get much lower muzzle velocities, and much more fouling.  Not something you want to use in a semi-auto or full-auto gun for very long.  It will jam like crazy, both due to the fouling and the lower muzzle velocities.

Comment: The Colt Model 1911 was made to safely fire cartridges with black powder.  This was important in the year 1911, when it was adopted as a standard issue sidearm by the US Army.  This was considered important given smokeless powder shortages in World War 1, and again in WW2.  The same cartridge was used in the Model 1928, a small machine gun used widely by the infantry and in close quarters combat by tank and artillery crews.  Black powder use is possible because of the wide safety margin on the cartridge specifications.  Many cartridges share this safety margin, QC wasn't always a high priority

Answer (score 8):

Get medieval, get a crossbow!

A crossbow has simple enough construction and rugged enough parts that it should be able to handle a good deal of travel so that should fit your reliability criteria. The most vulnerable part would be the string but you could easily bring a few extras and as bows were developed by just about every human civilization at some time or another you should be able to trade for more strings as needed.

While high quality ammunition is of course preferable a crossbow has such simple firing that you could load it with even primitive projectiles and still have some level of effectiveness.

In terms of stopping power modern crossbows today are able to push 400 fps and higher and don't require the special loading mechanisms that their medieval counterparts required. This means you can fire a bolt fast enough to pierce armor and reload at a similar speed you might a single shot bolt action rifle.

Comment: Just [repeating crossbow things](https://hiconsumption.com/ek-archery-cobra-rx-adder-tactical-repeating-crossbow/).

Comment: Build a gunpowder barrel onto the side of the crossbow? So you have that powerful shot when you need it...just in case.

Comment: I feel like a crossbow would lean more towards power than towards accuracy and range compared to most modern firearms.

Comment: @Jonathan a modern crossbow can be as accurate as a scoped rifle at 80-90 yards, but yeah, due to the lower projectile speed it does have less range than a modern firearm

Answer (score 7):

KerrAvon2055 from the comments has the right idea. A SBR (Short-barreled rifle) AR-15 styled rifle, a parts kit or two, and a few ammo cans will probably last you two campaigns over unless you're using it to hammer nails or things go extremely poorly, at which point you probably have more pressing issues to worry about.

The standard AR-15 weighs in at around 6.5 lbs. The weapon platform is extremely modular so you can, and probably will want to, swap out some of the stock parts with meatier after-market ones, such as swapping out for a heavier barrel in 5.56x45mm. After all your tinkering, the rifle will still come in at under 8 pounds making it convenient to lug around. 5.56x45mm is also very light at ~12.5g a bullet. Adding in the magazine puts you in at about 500g per 30 round mag (1.1 lbs). 20 loaded mags will give you 600 rounds at 22 pounds, not a bad deal considering you can pack even more ammo tins on the cart.

You now have 30 rounds of semi-automatic fire that will defeat any man-worn armor you will encounter (I'm assuming you won't meet many men wearing 1/2in steel plate). This will go a long way if you don't plan on "conquering the continent with a machine gun." With proper cleaning and a dab of oil, the gun will run right as rain for a very long while. It's almost as if Eugene Stoner designed it for military use.

As DKNguyen has pointed out, circumstances might cause you to enter civilization for untold periods of times. Having a 2 foot long rifle strapped to your back or hanging from you at all times is not ideal for such occasions. If we're permitted a second armament, bring a carry pistol with another set of parts and accessories will be much more convenient. This weapon should ideally not be used much unless you live an exciting life so ammunition can be skimped on a fair amount. You will then need to decide if you want maximum concealment or a work-horse. The distinction boils down to a tiny pistol with usually a single-stack magazine (low capacity) and a meaty kick vs a larger pistol that is nicer to shoot with a double-stack magazine (more capacity). This is getting long so to wrap it up, you can never go wrong with a Glock.

---

One alternative answer to consider: You can simplify logistics by having your sidearm and primary use the same ammunition (e.g. both are chambered in 9mm). This can have the draw back of having either a beefy pistol or an anemic rifle but there are some pretty good carbine cartridges that play reasonably nice in both platforms.

Comment: Do you actually need something as big and heavy as a rifle when on one else has one? I mean, this is for self-defense against people without firearms isn't it?

Comment: @DKNguyen it may not be defense against just people. Could be larger animals as well. AR-15 isn't spectacular against large game, and certainly not dangerous game, but if being humane isn't a particular goal, it'll do the job, and better than a pistol. The single advantage of a pistol is handiness and concealment. If neither of these are factors, bring a rifle.

Comment: To follow up on this, as they used to say about the Winchester rifle "Load it on Sunday, and shoot all week long". If it's basically for self defense, just how much trouble is one planning on getting in to? 1000 rounds is 200 rounds a year for 5 years, 16 rounds a month. A subsistence hunter would have trouble going through all that. Beyond that, reloading supplies for 1000 rounds (bullets, powder, primers -- you already have the cases) is less than 15 lbs. A simple reloading kit, like a Lee Loader, is, what, 2lbs? No reason to forego modern tech for even an extended stay.

Comment: @DKNguyen A peasant with a spear or sword or club will kill you perfectly fine if you let him. The question was asking to stop such occurrences. Also, if money is no problem (and durability, which is not the case for this question), you can get an AR that weighs less than 4 pounds.

Comment: @Veskah I don't really see what most of your reply has to do with anything, nor do I see how a handgun would be ineffective against a peasant with a spear, sword, or club. If you let a someone kill you, it doesn't matter what you're armed with.

Comment: @DKNguyen Your first question is basically asking "why bring a gun to a knife-fight?". It's so you can shoot him without being stabbed. Also, rifles have a longer sight radius and the additional mass and ergonomics allows quicker and easier follow-up shots if needed.

Comment: @Veskah I know you don't think that guns over a foot long are the only guns that exist so I'm not sure how you interpreted my question as "why bring a gun at all?" Like I'm imagining going about your day carrying this thing everywhere. Also, what about in close quarters or indoors? Wouldn't rifles be more unwieldly and longer to bring out?

Comment: @DKNguyen this is getting in to Chat territory, but consider this. When professional Law Enforcement and Military entry teams go in a building for, example, a hostage situation, you may have noticed that the arm of choice is a light rifle. Given the choice and preparation, they take rifles. There are a lot of reasons for this not appropriate for this forum. As the saying goes: 'Sheriff, I see you have your pistol. Are you expecting trouble?' 
'No Ma'am. If I were expecting trouble, I would have brought my rifle.'

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't, I was answering as if you only got 1 weapon. If that was the case, you lose several advantages for not all that much by going with a pistol over a SBR especially if you're doing a lot of adventuring. Basically long range (realistically, anything over 50y), and by extension hunting of medium game, is all but out (unless you want a big revolver which is cumbersome). If you can bring multiple things then yeah, bringing a carry piece as well makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Veskah Yeah, but StackExchange doesn't just let you bring things into chat of your own accord for some reason. I think the difference with that is they KNOW they're likely going into a combat scenario, rather than just going about their day. After all, police officers don't carry those large guns like that on them all the time. Are you expecting to spend most of your time fighting? Or most of your time living your life? Though hunting is a good point. It just sounds very similar to recommending someone take a spear (a real weapon for combat) for self-defense on your travels rather than sword.

Comment: @DKNguyen Without more details from the OP, we're just speculating at this point. I'm going to edit my answer to include having a carry piece and the AR as the go-to "Things have gone sour" weapon.

Comment: If you're bringing two weapons I'd recommend a .357 carbine and a compatible revolver.

Comment: @DKNguyen a rifle allows you to reliably hit an archer farther away than he can hit you.  A pistol really doesn't.  Yes, the bullet will easily go that far, but your accuracy will suffer greatly.  The longer sight radius of a rifle is a major advantage.  It doesn't have to be a full-size AR15.  It could easily be one in a pistol caliber with a short barrel and folding stock.

Comment: Right idea but you probably want the AK-47 over the AR-15.  You can drag it through mud and it,ll still shoot.

Comment: A 9mm conversion kit for an AR-15 platform is easy to get, and in military service makes a decent (if slightly large) submachinegun. The FN P-90 Personal Defense Weapon (PDW) can be matched with the FN FiveSeven pistol that fire highly effective, but non standard ammunition.

Answer (score 5):

You want a [sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)) of some kind.

Roman era slings were as deadly as a [44 Magnum.](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4541318/Roman-sling-bullets-deadly-44-Magnum.html) In this specific case, the ammunition seems to have been manufactured to whistle as it flew, probably for the psychological factor.

Ammunition can be as simple as a pebble picked up off the side of the road, or a steel ball bearing, or even special purpose items made of ceramic with various chemicals inside to be released when they hit the target and break open. You could put nearly anything in there from flammable oil to noxious substances such as skunk spray. (Though I'll leave collecting that to you.)

All of the components can be manufactured from locally available materials in any era that humans have technology as advanced as leather. All of the components can be carried in adequate amounts to go through several combats without having to stop and manufacture new components or ammo. A sling can be nearly silent. It has a substantial range, though accuracy suffers over longer distances.

With some practice, you can fire two or even three stones at once. Or you can fire a larger stone, possibly as large as a half kilogram. You could bring down larger targets such as a buffalo. In extreme situations, and with some practice and a lot of luck, you could bring down a tiger. Though attacking a bear with a sling is likely to just make it angry.

A sling will attract little attention. In contrast, any anachronistic weapon will attract a lot of attention. If you walk around with a rifle you will have everybody in the neighborhood trying to take it off you. Some because they want it for themselves. Others simply so you won't use it on them.

You want a sling.

Comment: Aren't they rather hard to learn to use?

Comment: Picturing this ... hmm. stone his buff in head. henh,   Buff is charging, wow they are about as fast as a bear! grabs another stone.. whoops, dropped it, seems a bit agitated ... huh rock that cracks mans skull irritates buff, I guess they run into each other like for mating, maybe. oh-oh .. he's tiring... wait, he tripped on that bush, thought he'd be more nimble, random thought, if slings are so good why is everybody carrying sticks in cave art? oh stumble, cut left dude! left! LEFT! OH NO HIS LEGS NOT HIS LEGS ALL CROGGLED UP  OH SHIT THE TIGER'S OUT.... MAULIN HIM.

Comment: Seriously though, sling is great if you plan on trolling some early hominids, not a great look really. A guy with a boot knife and a chair can advance on you with no fear, no training available to you today will give you the advantage in melee with the fighting class of medieveal society,

Comment: Slings are difficult to master, but if you take the time, it is an amazingly effective weapon. Even in late antiquity, the "Ten Thousand" recruited a unit of slingers to provide ranged protection against Persian cavalry.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to reiterate the cap and ball recommendation, with a couple minor changes.

First, you'll want a few basic tools -- as noted, you'll want to know how to make black powder, and you'll want to *practice* making and using it, as well as extracting the saltpeter, before you cross over for the longer term.  You'll also want a bullet mold and lead ladle -- that will allow casting a few bullets at a time over an ordinary kitchen or camp fire.  Lead isn't hard to come by (or wasn't in our own 14th century) -- it was used for roofing and early plumbing (which gets its name from *plumbum*, the Latin word for lead).  You'll want to use pure lead; cap and ball doesn't want or need hardened lead such as you'd use if casting bullets for a modern handgun.

You'll also want a tool (which you can 3-D print from downloadable files) for making up paper cartridges -- again, you'll want to practice this before going.  Paper cartridges cut reloading time to make it comparable to that of a single action cartridge revolver, and thin enough paper was available (though relatively hard to find) in the 14th century, at least in our timeline.  You can make or buy boxes that will carry five or six paper cartridges and caps (the caps glued to a paper strip for handling) and protect the cartridges from damage.

The critical item, however, is a means of making the percussion caps.  This requires a special tool to punch the cap shell out of thin metal sheet (this is fairly easy to make in a small machine shop, or you may be able to buy one with a little Googling), and a supply of paper caps (for cap guns) to use as the filler for the percussion caps.  Don't forget to take a roll of shim stock (available at genuine hardware stores, small engine repair shops, and machine shop supply vendors) to make your caps from.

I'd also recommend a larger gun -- a modern reproduction of a Remington New Army (aka 1858) has the power of a .357 Magnum and is durable enough to count on for many years (as long as you clean it after every use and keep it oiled).  If your mold makes conical bullets (which hit harder, are at least as accurate, and have better range) some modern repro revolvers require a minor modification to the frame and rammer -- check this before you go, obviously.

Even with the upgrade to a .44, because you don't need to carry a large quantity of powder or lead (a couple pounds of each is a good start), the entire kit will only weigh 15 or so pounds and fit in a bag or roll around 8 inches in diameter and a little over a foot long.

Answer (score 2):

AK-47

Stamped parts designed to be locally sourced and easily replaced.

The entire design relies on loose-fitting parts that won't jam.

Create your black powder, your brass, and a mold for the bullet.

Then use a brass catcher to collect the spent brass for reload/reuse.

Semi-automatic fire should be fine, no need for 3 round burst or full auto.

Comment: Locally sourced? What if this is an era that has not yet started making steel?

Comment: You would need smokeless powder, but yeah, AK47 has the reputation of extremely reliable gun.

Answer (score 2):

A sling? Those are as deadly as a .45 ACP. If you can hit your target, that is.

Otherwise, I would suggest a hand-recharged air rifle, like the kind you can get at stores nowadays. I would suggest a simpler design, like maybe the [Girandoni Air Rifles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girandoni_air_rifle) that Lewis & Clark brought on their expeditions.

However, if you are willing to go out on a limb, I would have your guy use spring-powered centripetal rifle. This is because you could (a) conceivably use low-quality ammo, (b) the parts would last longer, (c) the failure modes would be nowhere near as catastrophic as on an air rifle, and (d) if something does fail, there is a small chance that you could get replacement parts; they just would not be as good of quality

Respectfully,

thescribe11

Answer (score 1):

## Electric airsoft

You want to shoot pebbles that can do damage. It probably won't kill opponents but discourage them even with the light bullets. You can get 6mm metal spheres from jewelers, which are way heavier than your .15g plastic bullets (from gold they are ~[2.18g heavy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=113.097%20mm3%20gold%20weight)). You will probably have to bring two custom designs that have stronger and more robust mechanisms than commercially available, one acting as backup.
You need to bring solar charger panes with you, which you can use to recharge (for your other magicks you will probably need them anyway).
The 2.18g pellets at 100m/s deliver around [11 J impact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airsoft#Ballistics_and_velocity), which is a 30th of a 9mm handgun but already potent.

Comment: The heaviest I found were .46g BBs for snipers commercially available.

Answer (score 1):

So hopefully this will not get me put on any no-fly lists. But basically a potato gun. you could make one out of whatever you needed even wood, though metal would be ideal or some future material, any way you basically make a potato gun you can load whatever you need into it be in grenades, plasma grenades or just rocks added bonus, you can set them on fire with gasoline or tar which can be found it medieval time, added added bonus if you want more power set up a modified diesel engine for higher pressure and power I worked for a guy who had a motorcycle like that, it could run off of bacon grease which can be found in medieval times also other stuff oils and the like. If you want more of a machine gun you can have a revolver of sorts. Set it up with pressurized chambers that you pump up before the fight. you fire, then the next camber comes up the fire again. with a spring this can be as fast for slow as you want. also if you have a adjustable barrel sized you can be fairly accurate as well essentianlly this can be as simple or complex as you want the more complex the hardder and thereofre an hgher level of tec you need to fix it also you make one of thease that is just a flame thrower. One last thing you can ajust this gun like crazy want a shot gun put lots of small pelletes intot he chamber want a sniper get a long barrlet and a scope. the one downside is that you need to pump it up but with the deaise engin this will not take long. And all guns need realoding plus if you have the revolver set up when you run out but rocks lets say in you chambers close all of them put a oil in the engine and wait five seconds and your back in the fight. Hope this helps and safe travels.

any questions fire away!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring along a firearm, a shotgun is your best bet. Reloading shells is simple and (in my experience, your mileage may very) you can reload a single plastic hull about 10 times before the crimping starts to break apart. To reload a shell, all you need is a primer, some powder, a wad to create a seal between the primer and powder, and something to project. A simple press can be made to punch the old primer out, press a new primer in, slide a wad in, and crimp the top. You can also do all this by hand, but at a slower rate. Projectiles can range from rock salt to large metal slugs and anything else you can fit into the shell.

The shotgun itself can be reduced to almost no moving parts, depending on your choice. If you want something simple and reliable, I would suggest a side-by-side or over-under shotgun. The trigger mechanism will be your only moving parts (the shell ejectors and the breech hinge are technically moving, but it's trivial to keep them greased up) and the barrels will be very easy to clean. Since there is no rifling, a rag and a stick are all you really need. To keep the barrel in pristine shape, a plastic solvent can be used, but you can still get years of use out of the gun without ever cleaning it, at least with smokeless powder.

Comment: Yep. If I was optimizing for number of shots fired over time I'd pick a mechanically simple shotgun, some ammo, a carton of powder and a bunch of primers.
If I then got to the point where I had to make my own ammunition from scratch (ie make my own shotgun shell hulls, powder and primer etc), I can't imagine any weapon that would be more tolerant to that sloppy homemade ammo than a shotgun. I'd also look into brass hulls in order to put off having to make my own, but I'm not sure about them.
That's assuming a shotgun is capable of doing whatever this guy wants to do of course.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are all pretty great but the first thing I would look at is the fact that you would be going into an uncertain technological time period.
We have specialist weapons and ammunition for different scenarios for a reason.

The thing I would suggest is that whatever you have must be fully reusable and maintainable by very simple methods, finding the components for gunpowder in a jungle whilst being hunted by a wild animals would be difficult and getting the time and relative calm to press bullets into shell casings might be difficult too.  Anything electrical is susceptible to component damage and solar power will not help you very much unless your story takes place somewhere near the equator away from jungles and forests.

Depending on your starting technology I would suggest some kind of pneumatic system powered by some spell or ability your warlock has (not necessarily electrical).
If you were able to create some kind of spear that could launch a detachable head with enough force to produce the results you are looking for I would suggest that would be your best option.  While this may not be as accurate as you might like, accuracy in firearms is actually pretty difficult to achieve unless you rely on modern technology which I would try to avoid in the circumstances you describe.

In the worst circumstances you could attach something to the spear head to allow you to pull it back easily, in better ones you could have several spearheads that you could retrieve later.

Depending on what you want to do in your world you could also pass it off as a regular spear with some odd bits added on to it, that way you would only get some odd looks when you rock up with a weird spear rather than outright fear.

This has the advantage of the fact that all the maintenance you would need to do would be whatever you would do to a spear anyway.  Of course this all assumes that the launcher is created in a robust way.  Additionally it does not have to be a spear head, you could have a trident or net head if you wanted to use it for fishing, a heavy, round head if you wanted to smash through a wall or something and no head if you just wanted a short blast of compressed air.

If all this fails then my only other advice would be knowledge, having a repository of fairly advanced things you can make from much older technology would put you head and shoulders ahead of anyone else of the time.  If you know how to make gunpowder easily then you would be better off than those who do not, if you know about rifling then you would be able to make more accurate guns, if you know about the glass required in scopes then you can shoot distant targets more accurately.
These examples are just what I can think of off the top of my head, there are bound to be many others.

Answer (score 0):

A mass driver made entirely from chunky components and powered by a capacitor that is charged from a hand crank electric motor. I say this without having an example. But, it feels like something that would be relatively hard to damage if built the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Use fear, religion and money. The strongest defense in a medieval circumstance is to use the levers that the feudal lordship and/or religious order use to assert power over the masses. Declare yourself through your travels as you see fit, but the majority of people are still living arduous lives, ruled by tyranny. Money, wit and doctrine of title will protect you more than any weapon and will open many more doors.

That and using your numbers as a pack defense should be sufficient. Everything else is basically overkill.

You might as well bring a tech enhanced Steam Powered Land Ram. [LINK](https://www.google.com/amp/www.tanks-encyclopedia.com/ww1-gb-cowen-land-battery-devastator/amp/)